# Entity Framework Association Class possible?

Tags: entity-framework, associations

[image: Association Class in MDrive]

This is the way I can create an „association class“ in MDriven.
Is there an equivalent in Entity Framework (especially EF Core)?

I am aware that this can be done by this:
[image]

but this is not really „elegant“, I‘d rather prefer something the first way.

How can the first version be coded (Code-First) in EF.Core (if possible)?

TIA,
Levend

Comment: Here‘s a detailed explanation of the differences: https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/Association_classes

Comment: EF (and only some versions) only supports pure junction tables, i.e. only having two FKs. Since `Booking` is more than that you always need an explicit class. That said, isn't the first picture merely a (useful) UML expression? The *physical* implementation of both diagrams won't differ.

Comment: Yes, technically both have the same result on DB level. However the linked article explains the high-level differences quite good.

Comment: Pretty self-satisfied bunch there. I'm astounded to see such condescending language in product documentation. Anyway, as said, it's not supported. You can't have a `person.Flights` collection managed by EF. You can, of course, create methods like `Person.AddFlight` and `Person.RemoveFlight` which would be a totally satisfactory implementation of the encapsulated association they're so fond of.